# Can comments be made to count as activity?

Tags: discussion, comments, recent-activity

Currently, comments don't bump a question on the ['recently active' questions view](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active); only edits and new answers do. Comments also don't notify anyone except the question/answer owner they are attached to. As such, **late comments are more or less invisible** except to the affected users.

- New users may not yet know to use the @username format to notify the one they're responding to (e.g. [[1](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21731)] [[2](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21558)]); this would help their comments' visibility.

  - I hear that there's [a feature that displays activity for partaken questions on the user's profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093), but

    - few people here probably visit this specific page but instead rely on the (much more visible) notifications, and
    - it doesn't actually seem to work for me -- or I just am not looking at the right place.
- Someone may leave a late comment on an older question that inspires someone else to write a new answer from, say, a different viewpoint. (Or leads to a new question.)

It would therefore be nice for comments to cause questions to be bumped. There is not enough activity currently on this site for this change to cause chaos. Typically under 20 questions + answers + edits per day, combined.

Is this idea any good? Can it be implemented?

Comment: I imagine it is very much by-design that comments do not bump posts to the front page (on a more active site, comments bumping posts could be a real mess). The "feature" you linked to was never actually implemented; instead, the comment @-notification system that we now have was created.

Comment: Incidentally, if you particularly care to see the most recent comments on the site, you can [use the API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments#page=1&pagesize=50&order=desc&sort=creation&filter=!Fcb3plM_-PAl.9W5foSYllOGYS&site=japanese&run=true).